# Java Script | Random image in HTML5 picture tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, random, srcset

Trying to make random images (I have a set of images, all following the pattern "imgN", where "N" is a number from 1 to 9) with HTML5 picture tag. No good till now. This is what I'm trying:

HTML code is:

```
<picture id="heroimg">
    <source class="rand_webp_srcset" srcset="img1.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source class="rand_jpeg_srcset" srcset="img1.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <img class="rand_jpeg_src" src="img1.jpg">
</picture>
```

Javascript code is:

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1
document.getElementsByClassName('rand_webp_srcset').srcset = 'img' + randomNum + '.jpg';
document.getElementsByClassName('rand_jpeg_srcset').srcset = 'img' + randomNum + '.jpg';
document.getElementsByClassName('rand_jpeg_src').src = 'img' + randomNum + '.jpg';
```

Any cue?
Thanks.

**EDIT:** This is how I got it:

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1

var img = document.getElementById("rand_webp_srcset")
img.srcset='img/universo' + randomNum + '.webp'

var img = document.getElementById("rand_jpeg_srcset")
img.srcset='img/universo' + randomNum + '.jpg'

var img = document.getElementById("rand_jpeg_src")
img.srcset='img/universo' + randomNum + '.jpg'
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection, and that does not have src or srcset attributes. You need to loop over the collection, or access a specific element in it via index.

Comment: You should try to debug Your JS code. Use `console.log()` for example. In Your case: `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('rand_webp_srcset'))` would give more information about what You're doing wrong.

As @CBroe stated above - You would see collection to iterate, instead of single element

Answer (score 2):

When you use the function `document.getElementsByClassName()`, an array is returned. Just add the index of the item that you want to modify i.e. `document.getElementsByClassName('rand_webp_srcset')[0]`. However, in this case, using id's would work a lot better - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

```js
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1
document.getElementsByClassName('rand_webp_srcset')[0].srcset = 'img' + randomNum + '.jpg';
document.getElementsByClassName('rand_jpeg_srcset')[0].srcset = 'img' + randomNum + '.jpg';
document.getElementsByClassName('rand_jpeg_src')[0].src = 'img' + randomNum + '.jpg';
```

```html
<picture id="heroimg">
  <source class="rand_webp_srcset" srcset="img1.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source class="rand_jpeg_srcset" srcset="img1.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
  <img class="rand_jpeg_src" src="img1.jpg">
</picture>
```